# Can't install haskell accelerate-cuda package

Tags: gpu

Having trouble installing this package. I've tried removing all my hackages and reinstalling -- to no avail. Any ideas?

```
batterman-mbp:parallel batterman$ cabal install accelerate-cuda -fdebug
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: accelerate-cuda-0.15.1.0 (user goal)
trying: transformers-0.5.0.0/installed-4be... (dependency of
accelerate-cuda-0.15.1.0)
trying: SafeSemaphore-0.10.1 (dependency of accelerate-cuda-0.15.1.0)
trying: stm-2.4.4.1 (dependency of SafeSemaphore-0.10.1)
trying: language-c-quote-0.11.4 (dependency of accelerate-cuda-0.15.1.0)
next goal: exception-transformers (dependency of language-c-quote-0.11.4)
rejecting: exception-transformers-0.4.0.2, 0.4.0.1, 0.4, 0.3.0.4 (conflict:
transformers==0.5.0.0/installed-4be..., exception-transformers =>
transformers>=0.2 && <0.5)
rejecting: exception-transformers-0.3.0.3 (conflict:
transformers==0.5.0.0/installed-4be..., exception-transformers =>
transformers>=0.2 && <0.4)
rejecting: exception-transformers-0.3.0.2 (conflict: stm==2.4.4.1,
exception-transformers => stm>=2.1 && <2.4)
rejecting: exception-transformers-0.3.0.1, 0.3 (conflict: stm==2.4.4.1,
exception-transformers => stm>=2.1 && <2.3)
rejecting: exception-transformers-0.2 (conflict: language-c-quote =>
exception-transformers>=0.3 && <0.5)
Backjump limit reached (change with --max-backjumps).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing accelerate first. Then cuda and other libraries (some with aptitude or similar). Accelerate-cuda should then pass. Look if you have the latest ghc (7.10).There may be problems with older versions.